# How to sort combination of integer and text in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table

```
id  value 
1   OK
2   xminimum
3   NO
4   YES
```

I want to sort this table by `value` where `minimum` is always first then the rest according to alphabetic order of `value`  column

Meaning:

```
xminimum
NO
OK
YES
```

I wrote this query:

```
Select *
from table_a
order by case when value='xminimum' then 1 else ????? end
```

I don't know what to put in the else... conceptually it should be `else value end` so it means alphabetic order.. but I can not combine integer with text.

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `else 2`, or `else 0`? Then add another item  `, value` to the ORDER BY.

Comment: Didn't think of that. It works.. excellent :) post it as reply so I can accept

Comment: @jarlh, you should be posting that as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested, copied from my comment:

```
Select *
from table_a
order by case when value='xminimum' then 1 else 2 end, value
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
ORDER BY value <> 'xminimum', value;
```

Comment: What happens if a value is NULL?

Comment: NULL <> x is always NULL, as by default the NULLs are first my solution was wrong, good point :-) I update it.

Comment: I just checked, NULLS LAST is the default in ascending order, so my solution was correct in the end :D And the answer to your question is: "It will be put as the last result." :-)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out! (Some dbms products may have NULLS FIRST as default.)

Answer (score 1):

Do it like you have and add the `value` column as second column to sort by:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_a
ORDER BY CASE WHEN value='xminimum' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, value
```